# Temporal Error 9330 during view creation in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, temporal-database

I have a table where VALIDTIME and TRANSACTIONTIME columns are present.

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE T.TestTable ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      KeyId VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      ValidityPeriod PERIOD(TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE),
      BusinessTimePeriod PERIOD(TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE) NOT NULL AS VALIDTIME,
      TransTimePeriod PERIOD(TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE) NOT NULL AS TRANSACTIONTIME
      )
      PRIMARY INDEX KeyNUPI ( KeyId );
```

And there is a view on above table in a view database.

```
REPLACE VIEW TV.TestView
AS LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS 
NONSEQUENCED VALIDTIME
SELECT
    KeyId,
    ValidityPeriod,
    BusinessTimePeriod,
    TransTimePeriod 
FROM T.TestTable;
```

Above objects are already present and I cannot touch them.

Now, I have to create view on the above view. This new is supposed to act as a Table, upon which many views will be built later.

```
REPLACE VIEW T.AnotherTestTable
AS NONSEQUENCED VALIDTIME
SELECT 
    KeyId,
    ValidityPeriod,
    BusinessTimePeriod,
        TransTimePeriod 
FROM TV.TestView
WHERE KeyId = 'ABCD';
```

So, far no problem. Now If I try to create another view on this, it shows me `Failure 9330 ValidTime qualifier requires at least one table with ValidTime`

```
REPLACE VIEW TV.AnotherTestView
AS
NONSEQUENCED VALIDTIME --many views with CURRENT VALLIDTIME and other options will also be built
SELECT 
    KeyId,
    ValidityPeriod,
    BusinessTimePeriod,
    TransTimePeriod 
FROM T.AnotherTestTable;
```

Appreciate any help to solve this.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Why don't you simply create those views on `T.TestTable` directly?

Comment: Due to some restrictions, i cannot create on table directly. I have to use views for everything.

Comment: They might lift that restriction if you explain them why you need it?